# I get this error after I insert an ImageView into my TableView cell

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints

I have a StackView on the left with two labels as in the screenshot, that's what error I get. I understand that the error is in the hierarchy and in the constraints, but I don't know what's wrong with me?

[image]

I tried to change the restrictions and reinserted the constrints, but I didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you an exact answer for constraint related to issue without having complete picture.

But it seems like you have multiple constraint which are trying to define height. if the button view is fixed then your top and bottom constraint of view will define height and you have explicit height constraints for same as well.

What you do is reduce the priority of height constrain and see if you are still getting same issue. Then you can focus on that issue.

Comment: what height priority are you talking about ? priority of ImageView height or labels or buttons ?

Comment: 'assistantHeight' SystemInputAssistantView.height == 44, I suppose this is button which has explicit height of 44